# false OR false = true in MySQL? Very odd behaviour

Tags: mysql, boolean, logic

Basically, my 0 OR 0 is returning 1 - that's not really what I wanted :) I'm not really sure why because if I select 0 OR 0 I get 0..

I think this could be because is_premium_dealer is an enum('0','1') rather than a bool (don't ask me why, I didn't design this database!)

Does anyone know if this is because of the ENUM, and if so how I'd cast it to an integer?

Thanks in advance!
John.

```
SELECT is_premium_dealer, company_name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM adverts WHERE user_id = users.id AND is_archived = 0) AS innerquery,
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM adverts WHERE user_id = users.id AND is_archived = 0 AND is_deleted = 0) > 0 OR is_premium_dealer = 1) AS logicissue
FROM `user_profiles_dealers` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON user_profiles_dealers.user_id = users.id 
LEFT JOIN `counties` ON user_profiles_dealers.county_id = counties.id 
LEFT JOIN `countries` ON user_profiles_dealers.country_id = countries.id 
WHERE (users.is_active=1) 
AND (((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM adverts WHERE user_id = users.id AND is_archived = 0 AND     is_deleted = 0) > 0) OR is_premium_dealer > 0) 
AND company_name like '%autocraft%' limit 5\G
```

The result:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
is_premium_dealer: 0
company_name: A Company
innerquery: 0
logicissue: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Believe I might be able to wrap is_premium_dealer in BINARY(is_premium_dealer).. just testing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to wrap is_premium_dealer in the BINARY() function which seems to cast a string or anything into a binary value which can be evaluated as expected.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `is_premium_dealer = 1` filters records by ENUM **index**. From the documentation - *ENUM values are represented internally as integers*.

[The ENUM Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html).

Suppose we have - `enum_column ENUM('dog', 'cat', 'snake')`
then:

- `WHERE enum_column = 1` will show records where enum_column = 'dog'
- `WHERE enum_column = 2` will show records where enum_column = 'cat'
- and so on...

So, you can use number in WHERE condition and without BINARY function, just specify correct enum index.